# Print a few wanted lines from text with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I would like to print out the lines that are in bold. I tried using .find() to match with the string "X-Sieve" so that the loop would revolve only before it matches with the text, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I do it?

[image: Wanted lines are highlighted]

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:**

First of all, What is your current output? 'Not working' is not enough for us to understand. Second, try to use real code in your questions rather than images - people don't necessarily want to manually copy your code to test.

**Answer:**

In case your code prints all lines in the moment, just add the following before the `print` statement at the bottom of your code:

```
if 'X-Sieve' in hand:
   break
else:
   print hand
```

Comment: `if not hand.startswith('X-Sieve'): print hand` would be shorter